# Is current Raspbian Pi 3 B 32 or 64 bits OS?

Tags: pi-3

How do I verify my OS as 32 or 64 bits?

I need that to select NEW version of Eclipse, not the one which came with installing Raspbian  ? bit system

Comment: **Beware there is more to an [ISA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) than address size.**  You don't just need a 32-bit package, you need a 32-bit *ARM* package.  The regular *x86* 32-bit Eclipse will not work.

Comment: Please READ the question  - How do I verify my OS as 32 or 64 bits? I am not asking if Pi 2 is .... whatever HOW DO I VERIFY is the question.

Comment: That depends on the OS.  Presuming you are asking about Raspbian, the answer is in the second duplicate and implied by the first.

Comment: SO it is against policy to discuss , but it is OK for user to chase thru some ancient post? Very nice.

Comment: If you wish to understand the policy better, read *[What does it matter that my question is “unclear” or “too broad”, etc?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/794/5538)* and take note of the "billionaire in a restaurant" character.  The point is, if you want help of course it is fascinating to you and it would be great if everyone in the world chipped in.  However, this is likely a waste of resources, particularly when someone is asking a question that has already been asked before.

Comment: Is current Raspbian Pi 3 B 32 or 64 bits OS? [duplicate]How do I verify my OS as 32 or 64 bits?What is so unclear about this ? Wasting whose resources ? Wasting my time is OK? GET REAL You really expect new user not to ask what was asked before?

Comment: Again: **Read the second duplicate.**  Raspbian is **the same for all models**.

Comment: Recent Eclipse is x86 only.

Comment: @goldilocks, the problem with that is that in my many years of using stackexchange sites, I've in nearly every case had better information from the duplicates (and hence much more recent) and their conversations.  Two reasons for this.  1. Half the time, the votes to close are pile-ons that didn't fully read through either post, and 2. There are *Almost Always* nuances to a more recent answer and conversation that helps.  The rampant pedantry involved in enforcing this kind of thing is among the many reasons I asked to have my account scrubbed from SO.  The other sites are thus far not as bad.

Comment: @tgm1024 That is why I try to use the end of a chain rather than just the root; otherwise finding the other dupes, if any, takes a bit of savvy -- hint: the "Linked" sidebar stage right has them (and if you dig into that, you'll notice there was no such chain with this one at the time it was closed; there is another dupe from a month later linked to the root rather than this, but I did't close that one).  This also demonstrates to people just how many times their question has already been asked ;)

Comment: @goldilocks, yes, and to be fair, it seems that the moderators *do* understand the dynamic a bit better than the average pile-on folks.  In fact, I've had roaring arguments in meta-SO where the attitude was simply bonkers and it took a single moderator to shut them all up with a near immediate reversal.  However, this isn't the norm.  The simple fact of the matter is that for most sites, duplicate questions (if not "what does variable++ do") do not harm anything.

Comment: @goldilocks, pursuant to that, here's an example of how not all moderators ("over there") are not created equally.  Perhaps both you and janhus will appreciate this (eh, perhaps not).  It's one of my favorites, if only for it's incredulity: [lol](https://readmystuff.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/capture4.jpg)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the time of this writing, all officially supported operating systems are 32bit, and I'm not familiar with any unofficially supported 64bit builds that are particularly usable.

The command, `uname –m` will tell you what architecture your device runs on.

Comment: Close but no cigars None of the uname options , as far as I can tell, tells about the OS "bit structure".

Comment: Once you've done `uname -m` head over here to find out whether it's 32 or 64 bit: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136407/is-my-linux-arm-32-or-64-bit
My Pi 3 says `armv7l` which is 32 bit.